# How to handle a Java-error in an R-code on MacOSX?

Tags: java, r, macos, error-handling, shiny

When running my R-code using Shiny I get the following error message, only on my Mac (Catalina, V 10.15.1) but not on Windows:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Warnung in system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE)
  Ausführung von Kommando '/usr/libexec/java_home' ergab Status 1
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: kann shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so' nicht laden:
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

As my code is very extensive and long I cannot post it on here.
However, I would appreciate any help as I am still a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: Another option for reading Excel files is the "readxl" package, it does not have the JAVA dependence that "xlxs" has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS X does not come with Java Development Kits (JDKs) pre-installed.

I recommend installing via [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) then run the command:
`brew cask install java` and it will install the [latest Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and sort out any config for you.

Once you have the JDK, try running your R-Code again, it should be working fine and you should not see the *Unable to find any JVMs* error.